# provide for - sentence

Tags: word-order

I have found this in the dictionary but not sure whether I can separate these (from the examples on the internet, I think I cannot):

> I will provide for him.
>   I will provide him for ?? cannot be?

So it is not the same as:

> I will pick him up.
>   I will pick up him

which both seem to be correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will provide for him* means the speaker will make available the means for him to live. *I will provide him for* cannot be used to mean the same thing. When it is used, it has to occur with other words such as *I will provide him for one day only* or *I will provide him for $1000* and it might be said of someone being provided to perform some service or other. *Provide* can be used to describe the act of giving someone something, but then the construction is *I will provide him with . . .*

When the object of a phrasal verb is a pronoun, it comes before the adverb. So it has to be *I will pick him up* and not **I will pick up him*.

Comment: Also, it cannot be separated if it should mean exactly the same, right? I am concerned about the grammar, not the meaning. So "provide for" is something that is given and should always be in this form.

Comment: Yes, when it has the meaning of supporting someone in a material way, 'provide for' is inseparable.